# Split the decimal places in php

Tags: php

I am getting value in this format `2.00`. I want to show the value as `2`.How can i do so using php? My code to get value form the database is following and i am using `floor` function but evrytime i get value `0`.

**code**

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($rcv, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))$basic_info[]=$row;
foreach ($basic_info as $x)
{
$serial=$x['SERIAL'];   
$in = floor($serial);
}
 echo "$in"
```

**value in the database:**

**2.00**

**desired output:**

**2**

**currentoutput:**

**0**

Comment: use `number_format();` to remove decimal `$in = number_format($serial);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for that

```
number_format($x['SERIAL'], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `$in` value in `int`.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($rcv, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))$basic_info[]=$row;
foreach ($basic_info as $x)
{
$serial=$x['SERIAL'];   
$in = floor($serial);
}
 echo (int)$in; // here is change.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use typecasting.

```
$in = intval($serial);
```

Or

```
$in = (int) $serial;
```

Comment: That doest help. I am still getting 0 as output

Comment: Can you confirm if you are getting values in the loop? Use `var_dump($x);` in the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($rcv,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))$basic_info[]=$row;
 foreach ($basic_info as $x){$serial=$x['SERIAL'];
 $in = (int) $serial;} echo "$in";